# Can your staffs distibute your company non-distirbuted GPL licesned code?

Tags: licensing, gpl

Let say you use libmysqlclient to connect to MySQL, and since the client is GPL licensed and so your program. That's fine since you are the only one working on the project.

Then, you have a staff to join and contribute to the program, and he left. He own a copy of the program, can he freely distribute it because it is GPL lichened?

Comment: This would imply that giving a staff access to your internal code base constitutes a “distribution”.  But I don't subscribe to that interpretation.  And even if it were legal from a copyright law point of view, there might be other legal concerns that prohibit a former employee from making public information he gained during his employment.  But that would be specific to your jurisdiction.  I'm thinking of Germany, right now.

Comment: Typically (in many jurisdisctions), works produced under the direction of an employer are owned by the employer, not the employee. I do not have the right to source code (gpl or otherwise) at previous employers.

Comment: @MichaelT That's true at least in Germany.  But in order to be allowed to distribute GPL'd code, you need not own the copyright.  I can legally mail you a copy of Firefox even though I don't own a single line of code in it.  So I don't think that this fact is relevant here.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to make your question answerable.  If you're not distributing the code to the public, then what is the point of the code being GPL-licensed?  If you're using someone else's GPL'd libraries internally, those libraries can still be redistributed by anyone; presumably that already happens.

Comment: @5gon12eder: the FSF themselves don't consider that to be distribution, either.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of things to take into consideration:

- In most jurisdictions, if you are hired to write code, or if you write code for your employer, then the copyright on the code you write is owned by your employer/the company that hired you.
- As long as code is not made available outside the company that owns the copyright, it is not considered to have been distributed under copyright law.
- If code isn't distributed, it doesn't matter what licenses are used on the code. Even if the combination of licenses is incompatible with each other. Having incompatible licenses just means that the resulting work can't legally be distributed.

So, if you are writing a closed-source program for company-internal use, that program can use GPL libraries and you still don't have the rights to the closed-source company code.